How to import libgphoto2 with CPM.cmake?
I'm trying to create a CMakeLists.txt file in my C++ project where I'm using CPM to get some dependencies. I've added some libraries, all good it seems, but now I need libgphoto2 and it's a C project that does not use CMake and it seems with a file system different than what CPM can handle ?
I can't find how to include or build it from my CMakeLists.txt. Any idea ?
Here's the full CmakeLists.txt :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(myapp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#CPM integration
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CPM.cmake")
    if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/get_cpm.cmake")
        file(DOWNLOAD "https://github.com/cpm-cmake/CPM.cmake/releases/download/v0.40.2/get_cpm.cmake"
                "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/get_cpm.cmake"
                TLS_VERIFY ON)
    endif()
    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/get_cpm.cmake)
endif()

# LIBGPHOTO2
CPMAddPackage(
    NAME libgphoto2
    VERSION 2.5.31
    URL https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2/archive/refs/tags/v2.5.31.zip
    DOWNLOAD_ONLY YES # Only download; we will build it manually
)
if(NOT EXISTS "${libgphoto2_BINARY_DIR}/libgphoto2.so")
    # Define a custom command to build the library with make
    message("Building libgphoto2 using make")
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${libgphoto2_BINARY_DIR}/libgphoto2.so
        COMMAND make
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${libgphoto2_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Building libgphoto2 using make"
    )
else()
    message("Detected libphoto2 already built, skipping")
endif()


# SPDLOG
CPMAddPackage("gh:gabime/spdlog@1.8.2")

# LIBZIP
CPMAddPackage("gh:nih-at/libzip@1.11.1")

# WEBSOCKETPP
CPMAddPackage(
    NAME websocketpp
    GIT_TAG 0.8.2
    GITHUB_REPOSITORY zaphoyd/websocketpp
    OPTIONS "WEBSOCKETPP_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF" "WEBSOCKETPP_BUILD_TESTS OFF" # Disable examples and tests
)
if (websocketpp_ADDED)
    add_library(websocketpp INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(websocketpp INTERFACE ${websocketpp_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
endif()

# BOOST (for WEBSOCKETPP)
CPMAddPackage(
    NAME Boost
    VERSION 1.84.0
    URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost/releases/download/boost-1.84.0/boost-1.84.0.tar.xz
    URL_HASH SHA256=2e64e5d79a738d0fa6fb546c6e5c2bd28f88d268a2a080546f74e5ff98f29d0e
    OPTIONS "BOOST_ENABLE_CMAKE ON" "BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES container\\\;asio" # Note the escapes!
)

# NLOHMANN_JSON
CPMAddPackage(
    NAME nlohmann_json
    VERSION 3.7.3
    # the git repo is incredibly large, so we download the archived include directory
    URL https://github.com/nlohmann/json/releases/download/v3.7.3/include.zip
    URL_HASH SHA256=87b5884741427220d3a33df1363ae0e8b898099fbc59f1c451113f6732891014
)
if (nlohmann_json_ADDED)
    add_library(nlohmann_json INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(nlohmann_json INTERFACE ${nlohmann_json_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
endif()

set(sources src/cpp/main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/cpp/services)
add_subdirectory(src/cpp/entities)
add_subdirectory(src/cpp/exceptions)

add_executable(myapp ${sources})

target_link_libraries(myapp 
PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog
PRIVATE nlohmann_json
PRIVATE libgphoto2 # doesn't do anything ?
PRIVATE libzip
PRIVATE Boost::asio 
PRIVATE Boost::container
)

target_include_directories(myapp 
PRIVATE ${websocketpp_SOURCE_DIR} 
PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
PRIVATE ${libgphoto2_SOURCE_DIR}/gphoto2/gphoto2 # where some .h files are, but not helping ?
)

#install(TARGETS myapp
#    RUNTIME
#    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin)
#install(CODE "
#    include(BundleUtilities)
#    fixup_bundle(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin \"\" \"\")
#    ")

#include(CPack)

it fails at compilation time when it goes over one of my #import <gpoto2/gphoto2.h> statements :
build/_deps/libgphoto2-src/gphoto2/gphoto2.h:38:10: fatal error: 'gphoto2/gphoto2-port.h' file not found
#include <gphoto2/gphoto2-port.h>

I need to be able to run cmake on linux and macos, my end goal is to build a container with the binary but one step at a time.
Thank you very much for your help.

PRIVATE ${libgphoto2_SOURCE_DIR}/gphoto2/gphoto2:  one gphoto2 part is already part of #include <gphoto2/gphoto2-port.h>, so I would not specify it as part of the include path.

Hi thanks for your answer. gptoho2-port.h is an import made in the source files of the library, I don't have the control here. I tried with only one gphoto2 on this cmake line, but then my own file wouldn't compile. Removed it completely but back to the error. I tried to include in cmake the directory of gphoto2-port.h but same.
